# CMake - Unable to find boost components

Tags: c++, macos, boost, cmake

I try to start a project with [mlpack](https://www.mlpack.org) in C++ on macOS 12.0.1 with an Intel-CPU.
For development I use CLion, gcc/g++ 11.2.0 (installed via Homebrew), Clion's bundled cmake 3.20.2 and mlpack 3.4.2 (also installed via Homebrew).

Building the project fails due to the following error:

```
CMake Error at /usr/local/lib/cmake/Boost-1.76.0/BoostConfig.cmake:141 (find_package):
  Could not find a package configuration file provided by
  "boost_program_options," (requested version 1.76.0) with any of the
  following names:

    boost_program_options,Config.cmake
    boost_program_options,-config.cmake

  Add the installation prefix of "boost_program_options," to
  CMAKE_PREFIX_PATH or set "boost_program_options,_DIR" to a directory
  containing one of the above files.  If "boost_program_options," provides a
  separate development package or SDK, be sure it has been installed.
Call Stack (most recent call first):
  /usr/local/lib/cmake/Boost-1.76.0/BoostConfig.cmake:258 (boost_find_component)
  /Applications/CLion.app/Contents/bin/cmake/mac/share/cmake-3.20/Modules/FindBoost.cmake:594 (find_package)
  CMakeLists.txt:19 (find_package)
```

This error occurs even though I followed the instructions and defined the paths to `boost_*_config.cmake`. Here's the `CMakeLists.txt`:

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.20)
project(cpp)

set(CMAKE_CXX_STANDARD 14)

include_directories(.)
include_directories(/usr/local/opt/armadillo/include)
include_directories(/usr/local/Cellar/mlpack/3.4.2_3/include/stb)
include_directories(/usr/local/opt/ensmallen/include)
include_directories(/usr/local/include)
include_directories(/usr/local/Cellar/mlpack/3.4.2_3/include/)

set(boost_program_options_DIR /usr/local/Cellar/boost/1.76.0/lib/cmake/boost_program_options-1.76.0/)
set(boost_math_c99_DIR /usr/local/Cellar/boost/1.76.0/lib/cmake/boost_math_c99-1.76.0)
set(boost_unit_test_framework_DIR /usr/local/Cellar/boost/1.76.0/lib/cmake/boost_unit_test_framework-1.76.0)
set(boost_serialization_DIR /usr/local/Cellar/boost/1.76.0/lib/cmake/boost_serialization-1.76.0)
set(boost_spirit_DIR /usr/local/Cellar/boost/1.76.0/lib/cmake/boost_spirit-1.76.0)

find_package(Boost 1.76.0 REQUIRED COMPONENTS program_options, math_c99, unit_test_framework, serialization, spirit)

message("${Boost_INCLUDE_DIRS}")
message("${Boost_LIBRARIES}")

include_directories(${Boost_INCLUDE_DIRS})
add_executable(cpp
        cifar_train.cpp
        cifar_eval.cpp)
target_link_libraries(cpp ${Boost_LIBRARIES})
```

The C++ code is just one of the mlpack examples, which can be found in their [Github repository](https://github.com/mlpack/examples/tree/master/cifar10_cnn).

Since I'm relatively new to both CMake and C++ I can only guess what's wrong. To me it looks like something is not linked properly.

Comment: Look closely on the component name in the error message: ``"boost_program_options,"``. It contains **terminating comma**. This is because you put a comma into `CMakeLists.txt`. In CMake commas are not used for delimit a function's parameters or so.

Comment: Tsyvarev is right. Using commata in cmake is almost never correct. Note that this has nothing to do with linking. CMake does not do any compilation or link steps itself, but it creates the files for a build system that can execute the build steps (e.g. makefiles or a visual studio project). The error occured when cmake tries to execute a package configuration script provided by your boost installation which basically provides your own project with the information about boosts library file locations, include dirs ect.

Comment: Thanks, this did the job!

Comment: @Tsyvarev You saved me hours if not days. Thank you